# Send 2 array of objects from jquery to MVC controller

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have the following method on Controller:

```
public ActionResult TestMultipleParameters(IEnumerable<TestM> competences, IEnumerable<long> extracompetences)
        {
            return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The object is:

```
public class TestM
{
   public string uid { get; set; }
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public bool IsFromParent { get; set; }
}
```

and from query I am trying to send this:

```
var competences = [ {uid: "a", Id: 1, IsFromParent: true}, {uid: "b", Id: 2, IsFromParent: false}];
var extraCompetences = [1, 2, 3];
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
$.ajax({
   url: ...,
   async: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({ competences: competences, extracompetences: extracompetences }),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'GET',
    error: handleException,
    success: function(data){
        console.log("success");
    }
})
```

I tried many combinations between JSON.stringify and not stringify but the data is not sent to the MVC. Without JSON.stringify the array is sent to the controller but the values of the TestM are the default ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You making a GET. A GET has no body and your `contentType` option is ignored.

You can either make a POST to a method decorated with `[HttpPost]`, or alternatively you need to generate the name/value pairs with indexers, however the data will be sent as a query string and there is a possibility that you will exceed the query string limit and throw an exception.

If making a GET, then the `data` would need to be in the format

```
data: { competences[0].uid: "a", competences[0].Id: 1, ..... competences[1].uid: "b", .... },
```

Comment: I change the ajax call to POST, but now I get this error: "System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: competences."

Comment: You still need `data: JSON.stringify({ competences: competences, extracompetences: extracompetences }),` and `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` if you have changed it to `type: 'POST',` (and marked the method with `[HttpPost]`. And as a side note, you do not need `traditional = true` - that is only applicable for arrays of simple values